# If $f(n)=O(g(n))$ can I say there exists a $n_0$ for a specific $c$?

Tags: asymptotics

I've been working on an asymptotic proof and I want to start with saying that since $\log z=O(z)$ then $\log z\le\frac1 9z$ for $z\ge z_0$. In this example I'm picking $c=\frac1 9$ and hoping $z_0$ exists, but is $z_0$ guaranteed to exist if I pick $c$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take as an example $f(n) = g(n) = n$ and $c = 1/2$. Does there exist an $n_0$ such that $f(n) \leq cg(n)$ for all $n \geq n_0$?

In your case, you know more: $\log n = o(n)$. This means that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log n}{n} = 0,
$$
which implies that for every $c$ there exists $n_0$ such that $\frac{\log n}{n} \leq c$ for all $n \geq n_0$.

Comment: I think this makes sense. Since the limit is approaching zero, for any given $c$ the $n_0$ will be the $n$ where $\frac{\log(n)}{n} = c$?

Comment: You can take this $n_0$ since $\frac{\log n}{n}$ is monotone, but in general you are not guaranteed anything like that.